# How to do SQL Search Without knowing Column name?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I have a table which has product attribute names and product attribute values.

Somewhat like this:

```
PAName1 PAValue1 PAName2 PAValue2 PAName3 PAName3 PAName4 PAName5

Height 6ft       Length  186cm    Weight   74kg   Name     John
Length 190cm     Height  6ft      Weight   83kg   Name     Mathew
Weight 55Kg      Length  186cm    Height   5.5ft  Name     Anthony
Name   Peter     Length  186cm    Weight   74kg   Height   6ft
```

How will I select rows where the height is 6ft.?

I know how to use `In` command where I can select all PA to find this,  but I am looking for better solution,

Just want to edit something that i currently dealing with millions of rows where some rows have different Product Attribute. For example some rows doesn't have Height as a value, they might have Country. Some row doesn't have anything just the Name. Which stopping me to create a new table with new Column Name as i cannot control the data input..

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a simple

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (PAName1 = 'Height' AND PAValue1 = '6ft')
  OR (PAName2 = 'Height' AND PAValue2 = '6ft')
  ...
  OR (PAName5 = 'Height' AND PAValue5 = '6ft')
```

But a better approach would be to store those values in a corresponding columns. Try to redesign your table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
  Id     uniqueIdentifier,  
  Name   varchar(255),
  Height float,
  Length float,
  Weight float
);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. But i dont knw what is Product attribute Name or value to be..It might be height , or something else like Country..So i need to create something dynamic..I was looking to use XQuery currently.. But still Searching for right answer..Bcoz i am dealing with million of rows..

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear (at least to me) how your product names, attributes, and values all tie together.  I suspect your sample data has left out the product name.  If so, I would create this as an [Entity-Attribute-Value table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.product_attributes
(
    product_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    attribute VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(255) NULL
)
```

Then you can query it like `SELECT * FROM dbo.product_attributes WHERE attribute = 'Height' AND value = '6ft'`

Comment: Hi Guys i think i found the way to solve the problem easily. We can Use XQuery to solve the problem. i just have to create Product Attribute XML Schema Collection and load the name and value there. Then i retrieve the value using .Query and .Value.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I didnt test , but try the following

EDIT

```
;with p AS
(
    SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,LEFT(Height, len(Height)-2)  AS HeightValue FROM YourTable 
 )
select * FROM p WHERE p.HeightValue ='6'
```

**Note**

```
len(Height)-2  to exclude the ft from the height value
```